# ожидание setTimeout

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

При таком коде в консоль выходит `1,3,2`, а нужно `1,2,3`. Подскажите, как это реализовать с помощью промисов и коллбеков. `setTimeout` в функции `b()` эмулирует ожидание от сервера.

```js
function a() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(3);
  }, b())
}

function b() {
  console.log(1);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(2);
    return 2000;
  }, 5000)
}
a();
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О том, в чем именно ваша проблема уже написали в соседних ответах. Я же приведу решение задачи с использованием *Обещаний* (*Promises*):

```
function a() {
    return b().then(function(timeout) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        console.log(3);
    });
}

function b() {
    console.log(1);

    return (new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
    })).then(function() {
        console.log(2);

        return 2000;
    });
}

a();
```

А вот и [работающий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpr0e6qd/1/) на JSFiddle.

Если исходный набор функций не существенен, то все можно сделать несколько проще:

```
(new Promise(function(resolve) {
    // Получаем данные с сервера
    console.log(1);
    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(2000);
    }, 5000);
})).then(function(timeout) {
    // Обрабатываем данные синхронно
    console.log(2);

    return timeout + 1;
}).then(function(timeout) {
    // Обрабатываем данные аснихронно.
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('Foo-Bar-Baz');
        }, timeout);
    });
}).then(function(data) {
    // Выводим данные
    console.log(3);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: а почему на  JSFiddle? Тут же теперь есть всё свое и даже лучше, сразу показывает и консоль. Кстати, мне кажется вы не совсем правильно поняли автора, суть вопроса была в том, чтобы эмулировать ответ от сервера, то есть 1 это запрос, 2 это ответ, 3 это работа с полученными данные. То есть самый большой промежуток должен быть между 1 и 2, а потом сразу отрабатывать 3.

Comment: ну ты и завернул :-)

Comment: @MasterAlex, ответ обновил. теперь промежутки действительно между выводами. А что касается местного редактора -- он мне не нравится. Ну сам рабочий пример, по-факту, вторичен.

Comment: @Grundy, что-что?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, promise в таймуате возвращающий таймаут для promise с таймаутом :-D

Comment: @Grundy, таймаут = аснихронная операция. Ну и как всегда - если у вас есть ответ лучше, вы всегда можете его написать

Comment: что-то в варианте "проще" как-то ни разу не проще выглядит :-) мне кажется проще что-то вроде вот такого было бы :-) хотя может просто запись другая :) https://jsfiddle.net/Lpr0e6qd/2/

Comment: @Grundy, увы таймаут -- не самоцель. Каждый из них можно заменить _своей собственной_ асинхронной функцией. А проще второй пример потому, что в нем однозначно прослеживается поток данных.

Comment: там таймуат символизировал просто асинхронную операцию :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Устанавливаем серию событий по таймеру

### 1. В чём ошибка

В вашем коде функция `a()` устанавливает таймер на основе значения, полученного от функции `b()`. Но `b()` ничего не возвращает, потому что строка с `return 2000;` оказалась внутри функции `function()`, которую вызывает таймер. Из-за этого `a()` пытается поставить свой таймер на `undefined` и команда `console.log(3);` исполняется тут же, без паузы.

---

### 2. Если устанавливать таймеры, начиная с первого

Запускаем следующий таймер после того, как отработает предыдущий.

Ваш код может быть таким:

```js
a();

function a() {
  console.log(1);
  setTimeout(function() { b(); }, 5000 );
}

function b() {
  console.log(2);
  setTimeout(function() { c(); }, 2000 );
}

function c() {
  console.log(3);
}
```

В общем случае можно так:

```js
  
var delays = [ 5000, 4000, 3000, 2000 ];

delayConsole(0);

function delayConsole( i ) {
  if( i < delays.length ) { 
    console.log( (i+1) + '. ' + delays[i] );
    setTimeout(function() { delayConsole( i+1 ) }, delays[i] ); 
  } else {
    console.log( 'the end' );
  };
}
```

---

### 3. Если устанавливать таймеры, начиная с последнего

Все таймеры запускаем сразу. Чтобы запустить очередной таймер, функция суммирует все предшествующие ему задержки.

Ваш код может быть таким:

```js
a();

function a() {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(3); }, 2000 + b() );
}

function b() {
  var delayB = 5000;
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(2); }, delayB + c() );
  return delayB;
}

function c() {
  console.log(1);
  return 0;
}
```

В общем случае можно так:

```js
var delays = [ 5000, 4000, 3000, 2000 ];

delayConsoleBackward( delays.length );

function delayConsoleBackward( i ) {
  if( i > 0 ) { 
    var sumDelay = delayConsoleBackward( i-1 ) + delays[i-1];
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log( ( i < delays.length ? i+1 : 'the end' ) + ' is after ' + sumDelay );
    }, sumDelay); 
    return sumDelay;
  } else {
    console.log( 1 );
    return 0;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**callback**

```js
// data(1, function(e) {console.log(e)});
data(1, e => console.log(e));

function data(i, callback) {
 console.log(i);
 setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(2);
  setTimeout(function() {callback(3);}, 2000);
 }, 5000);
}
```

**костыль**

```
a();

function a(s) {
    if(s == undefined) {b(); return;}
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(3);
    }, s);
}

function b() {
    console.log(1);

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(2);
        a(500);
    }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: Костыль получился, но вроде работает

Comment: работает, а все таки как правильно?

Comment: @HelpaMnePlz, добавил пример с callback